# Page Token to custom facebook share

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

What I need is more of a guide and I hope you can help me.

I have recently used a facebook custom share in each line of a table on my website.  I used the code I found here [Custom share code](http://help.woobox.com/customer/portal/articles/961650-creating-a-custom-share-button)

Everything works fine with that, BUT I found out that you can use this "share" only if you are connected to your facebook profile and it's important to me to be able to use it also with your facebook page. The message I got was "To continue, you'll need to switch from using Facebook as"

So I'm researching all day long, but I need a guide to avoid mistakes. I will make the start so you can get the step that I am into.

1) Followed the instructions I found [there](http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/)

To be more specific I visited facebook devs -> tools and support -> 
Graph API Explorer

2) Get access token -> extended permissions -> manage_pages (it was already enabled but I may have done it before without knowing what I was doing)

3) Get page access token for my facebook page

I still can't share as a facebook page

PS. I just figured out that following the steps I mentioned will enable the "share" only on my page.

So I am redefining my question

"How can I enable users, use my custom share, with their facebook pages and not only with their facebook profiles"

Comment: Access tokens are for doing stuff via the API, but using the Feed dialog does not make the post via API, but leaves all control in the hands of the user.

Comment: Getting an access token from the Graph API explorer will give the logged in user's access token. If you want other users of your app to be able to use their page access tokens, then you'll need to ask for manage_pages and publish_pages during login. Once you do that, make a call to /me/accounts to get the page access token of the user. You can then use this access token to publish/share content. Remember, you'll need to submit your app for review if you want to use these permissions in your app.